# Can we Use server side scripting for both web and app?

Tags: javascript, android, flutter

I am new to programming field and I am basically trying to built a system based on web and app which is web based where two users can communicate and buy products from each other on my platform. The question I want to know is there any sytem if i can just code server side logic and connect front end of both web and app to the same logic which is saved on the server.....I hope am able to clearify my question...sorry for the bad english

I was looking for different solution but can't find a reliable one

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can connect your website and flutter app, by using http pub
and get the data from api.

or you can build your website with flutter and in the same as app.

I hope that is answer your question, if not please explain more about what you mean

Comment: So basically i will only need to code front end of android app...and backend from web can be used?

Comment: Yes by using api and http package